# How to install metan packages in R Studio

Tags: r

I am trying to load metan in R Studio but after installing them, when I do library metan I get this message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘metan’ in
> loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘ggplot2’ 1.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required.
> In addition: The warning message: package ‘metan’ was built under R
> version 4.1.3

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what does the errormessage say? (hint: appearantly you need a newr ggplot. also, there is a newer version of R available than the one you have installed)..

Comment: the messaye said that: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘metan’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace ‘ggplot2’ 1.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required. In addition: The warning message: package ‘metan’ was built under R version 4.1.3